# chart.js animation loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I would like that my pie chart (with its animation) would be loaded during the scroll down of the page, how can I do this?

This is my code:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext("2d");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 20, 70],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(243, 89, 105, 1)',
                'rgba(174, 233, 244, 1)',
                'rgba(247, 239, 151, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
        }],
        labels: [
            'Test1',
            'Test2',
            'Test3'
        ]
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
            animateRotate: true,
            easing: 'linear'
        },
    }
});
</script>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var vis=0;
$( document ).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(document.getElementById('your-element'))){
        if(vis==0){

        //your code            

        vis=1;
        }
    }
});

function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemTop = rect.top;
    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    return isVisible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nicolas! I tried but seems not to work... you can see the complete code in my answer.. did I make some kind of mistake?